# How to set microphone volume for specific channel via command line?

Tags: command-line, microphone, audio-volume

There is a tool `pavucontrol` which can be used to setup input device channel (left or right) level. For example, I can set left front channel to -18dB and right front channel to -10dB by using GUI sliders.

Is there any way to setup different volume levels for different channels using command line?

P.S. I am able to setup microphone volume level using `pacmd` but it sets the same volume for both channels (I need to change volume for specific channel):
`pacmd set-source-volume alsa_input.pci-0000_00_09.2.analog-stereo 90000;`

Comment: `pactl` accepts multiple volumes (one for each channel) for `set-*-volume`, while `pacmd` only seems to accept a single volume. Don't ask me why there are two different tools...

Comment: Thank you for your comment! It is helpful. Can you provide an example of using `pactl` in the answer so that I can accept it?