# Pulseaudio: How to set individual sink volume for left, right or srround channel on commandline

Tags: command-line, audio, pulseaudio, volume

I have a 5.1 surround sound card and want to set individual volume for the different channel:

```
Sink #1
    State: RUNNING
    Name: alsa_output.usb-0d8c_USB_Sound_Device-00.analog-surround-51
    Description: CM106 Like Sound Device Analog Surround 5.1
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 6ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe
    Owner Module: 23
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 48434 /  74% / -7.88 dB,   front-right: 48434 /  74% / -7.88 dB,   rear-left: 48434 /  74% / -7.88 dB,   rear-right: 48434 /  74% / -7.88 dB,   front-center: 48434 /  74% / -7.88 dB,   lfe: 48434 /  74% / -7.88 dB
            balance 0.00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0.00 dB
[...]
```

**How to set the volume for `rear-left` by using the command line?**

I tried `pactl set-sink-volume 1.rear-left 100%` but thats not working.
The manpage even is not helpful as there seems to be no syntax for accessing the different channels.

Answer (score 0):

As noted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/506155/how-to-set-microphone-volume-for-specific-channel-via-command-line#comment934741_506155), `pactl` accepts multiple volumes (one for each channel) for `set-*-volume`.

So in your particular case

```
pactl set-sink-volume 1 74% 74% 100% 74% 74% 74%
```

should do the trick.